# How to create separate buttons for different devices?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've been using bootstrap to create a responsive web site. 
I've just come across a new scenario and I'm not sure how to resolve it.
I have the following html code:

```
        <!-- button color depending on desktop vs. phone -->
        <button class="btn visible-desktop" id="modifyVLANS">Modify VLANS</button>
        <button class="btn hidden-desktop lsm-visible-phone btn-warning" id="modifyVLANS">Modify VLANS</button>
```

Later on, I have the following jquery:

```
    //show list
    $('#modifyVLANS').click(function()  {
            do something....
```

However, becuase I have two buttons named the same, on the mobile device, the onclick event doesn't fire. 
I don't want to create two separate buttons with separate event handlers ... because the code would be the exact same. 
How can I get around this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use media-queries

Comment: I'm already using built in media queries.. you'll notice the classes like "hidden-desktop" "visible-desktop" etc.

Comment: You're using id to select the elements. `$('#modifyVLANS')` selects the first element with that id, and ignores the rest. You're meant to have one id per page, so it's an understandable behavior. Instead of using an id, you could use a class attribute. -> http://jsfiddle.net/NLzHW/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the buttons depending on the device, I would hide the entire form. I had the same issue when trying to implement one style of `<input type="search">` for mobile, and another for desktop.

Then, tie your event handler to the button `class` rather than an `id`, because even if one of the buttons is hidden depending on the view, you can **still only have one element with an `id` per page**.

Here's a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamdehaven/pfbBY/).

Comment: I was just going to post that I found a solution.  I've changed the click event to check for the class.  Thanks very much!